# The value of the variable input is a string 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. How would you get the sum of the integers contained inside input?

Tags: php

How would you get the sum of the integers contained inside input in php?

Comment: `explode()` it on the comma to an array, then `array_sum()`.... the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) have a lot of useful information about the functions that are available in PHP. It's always better to have a look there before asking for help on SO

Comment: @MarkBaker Like That : `<?php
echo array_sum(explode(',',$input));
?>`

Comment: @MarkBaker Its right or not?

Comment: You tell me whether it's right or not; you can test whether it works or not can't you?

Comment: @MarkBaker No currently i don't check but i think it's work

Answer (score 1):

Have tested and this works fine

```
<?php
    $input = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
    $output = 0;
    foreach(explode(',',$input) as $val)
         $output +=intval($val);
    echo $output; //28
?>
```